# Modify python array using graphical interaction (Bokeh or Javascript)

Tags: javascript, python, graphing

I have a 1-D numpy array eg.[1,0,6,3,2,1,6,4,3,2,1] which I have been able to graphically display as a histogram graph using the Bokeh Library.

I would like to be able to modify the array using graphical interaction.

Ideally I would like to be able to shift 1 value at a time.

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

[image: Example]
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Grid, LinearAxis, Plot, Quad,Range1d,HoverTool, Panel, Tabs,Legend, LegendItem,FixedTicker,NumeralTickFormatter,SingleIntervalTicker
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create Data
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Values= np.random.randint(0,6000,800)


def Values_to_Bins(Values, Bin_size): #takes in a numpy array of values, and the Bin size
    Min_Value = np.amin(Values)
    Max_Value =np.amax(Values)
    bins = np.arange(Min_Value, Max_Value + 2 * (Bin_size), Bin_size)  # Define bin edges
    hist_array, edges = np.histogram(Values,bins=bins)  # Create 2 arrays, hist_array represents the bin counts, edges is the bin edges
    return hist_array,edges #Returns the histogram array, and edges
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# STEP X: Create Bokeh Histogram Plots
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
hist_array,edges = Values_to_Bins(Values, 15)

# Create a Pandas Dataframe 
Bokeh_Bins = pd.DataFrame({'Values': hist_array, 'left': edges[:-1], 'right': edges[1:]})
Max_Initial_Bin = Bokeh_Bins['Values'].max()

# Create a column showing the extent of each interval
Bokeh_Bins['Bin_interval'] = ['%d to %d ms' % (left, right) for left, right in
                              zip(Bokeh_Bins['left'], Bokeh_Bins['right'])]

tick_vals = np.arange(Max_Initial_Bin + 1)

# Convert dataframe to column data source
src1 = ColumnDataSource(Bokeh_Bins)

plot = figure(y_range=Range1d(start=0, end=Max_Initial_Bin), sizing_mode="scale_width", width=3000, height=600,
              title="Want to create interactive Histogram data",
              x_axis_label="Time (ms)",
              y_axis_label="Number of occurances")
plot.yaxis.ticker = FixedTicker(ticks=list(tick_vals))

plot.quad(bottom=0, top='Values', left='left',
          right='right', source=src1, fill_color="#939393",
          line_color='black', fill_alpha=0.5,
          hover_fill_alpha=1.0, hover_fill_color='#00E400')

# Add hover tool for when mouse is over data
hover1 = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Timeframe', '@Bin_interval'), ('Count', '@Values')])
plot.add_tools(hover1)
original_script, original_div = components(plot)
show(plot)
```

Comment: I would be better when you include your question by the code you try?

Comment: @Nour-AllahHussein I've added the code

Comment: Did you check if the [PointDrawTool](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#pointdrawtool) satisies your wish?

Comment: Thanks @mosc9575. I think maybe PointDrawTool could be a possible solution, however I haven't figured out how to apply it to the histogram style graph.

Answer (score 0):

For making interaction modification with `Boken`, you can add a `Widgets` like `sliders` and others in which any modification made with these widgets will fire the corresponding call back functions. you can find good information at the following link:

```
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html
```

in that link, you will find plenty of examples in python.

and of course, welcome other support, I would give.

Comment: Thanks Nour-Allah. Yes I believe I need to incorporate some callback functions like you suggest. I haven't determined how to achieve this in the histogram style graph I am using however I will investigate further :)

Answer (score 0):

Each bar in the histogram corresponds to a set of data points. You need some rule (pick one at random? the smallest? the largest?) to move. Then when you move it to another bin, you also need to choose the value at which to set it (the bin center? left or right edge?  somewhere uniformly in the bin).

Once you have made those choices, it shouldn't be too hard to implement a callback where that implements the following pseudocode.

```
   [bin_edges, bin_counts, data_map] = histogram(data)
   [bin, y] = picked_bin() # This returns the value of your 1st mouse click
   [newbin, newy] = set_bin() # This returns the value of your 2nd mouse click
   possible_points = bin_edges[data_map] == x
   old_datum_ind = pick_one(data, possible_points)
   data[old_datum_ind] = assign_new_value(newx)
```

The key info is that `data_map` which is the same length as data but is the index that maps each datum in data to a bin. This lets you easily find out the data points corresponding to each bin.

Comment: Thanks @jerlich. I think if you were to take the largest value in the bin, and assign it to the mid point of the new bin that would work just fine. 
Are you able to provide a working example?

Comment: @Morgs i probably could, but i'm sorry i don't have time right now.